# Avoid vertical movement if an empty div gets one line of text

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 3 `<div>` in a column with  `flex` (this layout needs to stay).

**How to make that `#a` and `#b` take one full line height, even if empty? To prevent everything from moving when one line of text is inserted in `#a` and `#b`?**

If possible without hardcoding with a fixed number of pixels.

```js
document.getElementById("go").onclick = () => {
   document.getElementById("a").innerHTML = "a";
   document.getElementById("b").innerHTML = "b";
};
```

```css
#main { 
    height: 150px; 
    display: flex; 
    align-items: center;             /* i want to */
    justify-content: space-around;   /* keep this */
    flex-direction: column; 
    background-color: yellow; 
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
<div><button id="go">Click me</button></div>
<div><i id="a"></i></div>
<div><i id="b"></i></div>
</div>
```

Comment: are there ever 3 divs or can there be more? If there are only 3 then you can set the height to 33.33%
and please don't use ids to style, use classes instead

Comment: @c.m. I'm looking for a solution without hardcoding numbers, if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would disable the line-height but this will only work if it's one line of text and you have enough height to avoid the overflow.

```js
document.getElementById("go").onclick = () => {
  document.getElementById("a").innerHTML = "a";
  document.getElementById("b").innerHTML = "b";
};
```

```css
#main {
  height: 150px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: yellow;
}

#main i {
  line-height: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div><button id="go">Click me</button></div>
  <div><i id="a"></i></div>
  <div><i id="b"></i></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It even works without `line-height` at all and just `display: inline-block;`. Thanks!

Comment: @Basj no, you need line-height. It worked here due to some particular combination of values but if you have a different font-size or font-family it won't always work so keep line-height.

Comment: Thanks. What does setting it to 0 mean?

Comment: @Basj the height of the text line (the linebox) is equal to 0 so the height of the element is equal to 0

Answer (score 2):

Set children `height` to `100%`

```js
document.getElementById("go").onclick = () => {
  document.getElementById("a").innerHTML = "a";
  document.getElementById("b").innerHTML = "b";
};
```

```css
.main {
  height: 150px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;     /* i want to */
  justify-content: space-around;    /* keep this */
  gap: 5px;    /* you can remove this */
}

.main>div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: yellow;    /* you can remove this */
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div>
    <button id="go">click Me</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <i id="a"></i>
  </div>
  <div>
    <i id="b"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: flex:1 would be more logical than height: 100%

Comment: @TemaniAfif Why should the children `.main>div` also be in flex? What is the rationale for putting children in flex too?

Comment: @Basj I am not the one who provided this solution :)

Comment: @Basj I just did it to make it look better, simply ignore it

Comment: @TemaniAfif I tried flex-grow it didn't work

Comment: not flex-grow, I said flex:1

Comment: @TemaniAfif Oops I misunderstand you, sorry you're right, flex:1; also works